# replacing pixels in Matlab after resizing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, resize, image-resizing, pixel

I have a Matlab script (see below) that resizes a folder full of pictures (490 x 500) to a new size (512 x 512). Now, because the original pictures are not squares, what happens after resizing is that on the left and right side of each picture I get a white strip. This is probably an automatic filler to keep the proportion of the picture but at the same time achieve the 512x512 size.

What do I need to do to get rid of those white strips on either side of the pictures? Maybe replace the white pixels with black pixels, but how to achieve that strategy-wise?

```
clear all
close all

dir = 'D:\matlab_picture_edit\pics'; %location of images
outdir = 'D:\matlab_picture_edit\pics_new'; %location of directory for output images

cd (dir); % go to source dir
fs = filesep
dln = '.'

num = 1 % iterations of transform
images = cellstr(ls(dir)); % list all files in source dir
images = images(3:end); % remove first 2 lines (.., .)

 for h = 1:length(images) % all images
     flnmdel(h,:) = strsplit(images{h},dln) % split up file name
 end

for pic = 1:numel(images)
   image = images{pic};

   img = imread(image);

   img2 = imresize(img, [512, 512]);

   imwrite(img2,[outdir fs flnmdel{pic} '_s.jpg'] )   

end
```

Comment: I ran your code as it is, and I got the result that you required. i.e. no white space. (using MATLAB R2016a)

Comment: Tahnks @Sardar_Usama , I use Matlab R2015a. You might be able to see the white space on a black backround only (e.g. in powerpoint)? It does make sense to me because the original size is not square.

Comment: I've tried that on not square images as you mentioned in the question! There's no such problem. Your actual images probably have white spaces which get enlarged when you increase its size. Include a sample image in your post!

Comment: I used your image and code, still got no white strips!

Comment: Thank you Sardar_Usama , you are right! I ran it again and no problem this time. I will ask the question about replacing pixels separately, because I am still interested, but it has indeed nothing to do with my resizing script!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama, you ought to combine your comments into an answer so this question can be closed - it seems as though the OP has found a satisfactory answer to *this particular question*.

Comment: @VladislavMartin ! The OP ran his code again without  doing any change and it worked! What appropriate answer do you propose for that?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Yes; for this reason, it's a simple answer. "Your code works. I've tried that on not square images as you mentioned in the question! There's no inherent problem with your code as it currently stands. Your actual images probably have white spaces which get enlarged when you increase its size." I would have written the answer for you, but you answered it so you might as well get credit for it :) From the rest of the forums' perspective, it's wrong to leave a question open after it's already been solved. That's all I meant

Comment: @VladislavMartin  ! Thank you for all that !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with your code.

I've tried that on not square images as you mentioned in the question! Your actual images, probably, have white spaces which get enlarged when you increase its size.